# How to get model description list using c# in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get model description list (like Neck,Spine,lower lip etc) whatever is defined for a 3d character model ? I tried to write a script which is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Arrays : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] players;

    void Start()
    {
        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("avatar_5");  
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(players[i].name);
            Debug.Log("Player Number " + i + " is named " + players[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

but in result I am getting this error:
[UnityException: Tag: avatar_5 is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh4vH.png)

Comment: You're looking for a Tag with `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, not the Name of your object. Has your "avatar_5" the right Tag? (this is not the name).

Comment: so should i tried like GameObject.Find("avatar_5")

Comment: this will return only one GameObject. Mostly the first one with the exact name in the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Understanding

First of all, what you describe as `model description` are simple `GameObjects` in Unity3D. And your exception tells us that your `GameObject` hasn't the right tag on it.

Also there is a huge difference between an `GameObject`'s **Name** and his **Tag**.

[image: Can you see the difference?]

So if you want to print all children of a specific `GameObject` you have to find it first and then access it's child with `GameObject.GetChild()`.

As the comments mentioned, `GameObject.Find()` will only return the first `GameObject` with the exact name, not all. So we have to loop through all GO's for finding the one with the right name.

---

### Solving process

To accomplish your question, I guess we have to print the hierarchy of `GameObject`'s.
So we simply check all `GameObject`'s if there are parent Objects, and collect them in a list. Then we can loop through them and read their children.

For checking if a `GameObject` is a parent or has a Child we always have to look at the `Transform` Component of the given GameObject.

**Be aware of that, this kind of looping is very performance intensiv task.**

Here is some **example code**, for a better understanding of what I mean and how this behavior in Unity3D works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ReadAllGOs : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var parents = FindParentGameObjects();
        for (int i = 0; i < parents.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("--> Parent Number " + i + " is named: " + parents[i].name);
            ReadChildren(parents[i]);
        }
    }

    List<GameObject> FindParentGameObjects()
    {
        List<GameObject> goList = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach (GameObject go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
        {
            if (go.transform.parent == null)
            {
                goList.Add(go);
            }
        }
        return goList;
    }

    void ReadChildren(GameObject parent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject child = parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            Debug.Log(string.Format("{0} has Child: {1}", parent.name, child.name));
            // inner Loop
            ReadChildren(child);
        }
    }
}
```